# Access Private NPM Repo with DoD CAC

Tags: npm, smartcard

We're looking for a way we can get the `npm` command to use our DoD CACs (PKI, PIV, X.509, Smart Card) to authenticate with a privately-hosted repo, configured with PKI-based mutual authentication. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, we created a small java program that lets you proxy http requests through an CAC-enabled SSL tunnel. See [cac-agent](https://github.com/MoebiusSolutions/cac-agent).

This has worked well for us, allowing all services to be fronted by the same reverse proxy, but we're still open to other approaches.